# Keen IO JavaScript SDK usage for sending data/events

Tags: javascript, analytics, keen-io, data-collection

I am trying to use the Keen IO JavaScript SDK (keen.js) to collect and analyze my user events. I see documentation describing how to add new events but at times it refers to using the function recordEvent() and in others the function addEvent().

Do they do different things? Which should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those methods can be used to send events to Keen IO. The difference is which Keen IO JavaScript SDK you use for event tracking.

Use `addEvent` to record a single event and `addEvents` to record multiple events with [keen-js](https://github.com/keen/keen-js). Use `recordEvent` and `recordEvents` with [keen-tracking.js](https://github.com/keen/keen-tracking.js) (a library split out of keen-js, recommended for taking advantage of Keen IO’s most advanced event tracking functionality).